# Calculating receiver signal in CDMA

Tags: signal, code

I am struggling to understand how the receiver is able to differentiate between multiple CDMA users, who are transmitting at the same time.

[image: CDMA example]

In this figure for example, I understand each part, except from the final two rows, when I do the multiplication, I only receive an 0, while in the example, several integers are changed from positive values to negative or vice versa. For example in the bottom row, why does the -4 become a +4?

Answer (score 1):

> For example in the bottom row, why does the -4 become a +4?

The minus 4 is multiplied by a minus one. That makes plus four in the first position. Maybe you were thinking too hard and expected the minus four to be multiplied by all the plus and minus ones in the second bracketed set?

Comment: Ah, makes sense, thank you. I was over-complicating it like you said.